# Did I Brick my Controllino?

Tags: atmega328

I recently obtained a Controllino Mini to be used in a small industrial project. While checking it out I also wanted to test the built-in RTC capabilities. In doing so I toyed around with the available commands from the supplied [library](https://github.com/Controllino/ControllinoLibrary). After uploading another sketch it seems I have bricked the Controllino, since I cannot upload anything else :

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude:
>   stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

and the reset LED is permanently lid. When looking at the [pinout](http://controllino.cc/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/CONTROLLINO-MINI-PINOUT-02-10-15.jpg) diagram of the Controllino Mini I saw that there was a small remark  near the top stating

> Not proper handling of the RTC/INT output can cause permanent
>   controllino reset , so I guess I somehow reached that state.

Since I am pretty new to the whole Arduino / Microcontroller scene I don't really know where to go from here.

- Is it a viable idea to try and burn a new bootloader ?
- Is there a simpler way to reset the state of the device?
- What did I even do wrong ?

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Christian

Below is the sketch that got me into this mess:

```
#include <Controllino.h>


unsigned char day, weekday, month, year, hour, minute, sec;
#define analogInputPin A0
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(analogInputPin, INPUT);
Controllino_RTC_init(1);
Serial.print("Initalized RTC: ");
Controllino_SetTimeDate(1,6,4,2016,15,14,10);
}

void loop() {
 Controllino_ReadTimeDate(&day,&weekday,&month,&year,&hour,&minute,&sec);
  float voltage = 15*(analogRead(analogInputPin)/1023.0);
  Serial.print(hour);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(minute);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(sec);
  Serial.print(" : ");

  Serial.println(voltage);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received an answer from the official team which should work, I'll leave it here for further reference:

> 1. Open the device and disconnect (remove) connection board for approx. 30 seconds from the control board – RTC is disconnected from power (gold cap disconnected) and because of that there is reset of all RTC registers.
> 2. Plug the connection board back in to the control board. Now we need to rewrite the SW inside the Controllino which caused wrong RTC setting.
> 3. Open the Controllino example RTC sketch in Arduino IDE and prepare it to upload (function Controllino_RTC_init(0); shall reset all registers inside the RTC).
> 4. Pres and hold reset button on the Controllino device.
> 5. Connect the USB Cable (still hold the reset button, SW inside the Controllino doesn’t start)
> 6. Click for upload the sketch in Aruduino IDE and wait for „uploading“ message on debug line, than immediately release the reset button and uploading shall be finished (=> hold the reset button during the compiling phase)
> 7. If not successful, repeat the procedure

Comment: But did it work? Atleast it's nice to know they give a reasonable answer, but I'm curious if it fixes anything.

Comment: I will get back to you on that ;) I will probably be able to test it in a couple of hours

Comment: I just got to testing, it worked just fine and I can use my Board again :). it's probably notable that you only have to remove the very top of the boards which is connected via a very small pinheader to the board below. Take care not to break anything.

Comment: That's good news. Doesn't fix the underlying problem, but at least it's a reasonably easy way of recovering from it.

Answer (score 4):

It certainly looks like the INT pin of the RTC can kill the whole unit. Bit of a FUBAR on their part I would say.

> Is it a viable idea to try and burn a new bootloader ?

If the problem is that INT pin then you won't be able to replace the bootloader, and even if you did it wouldn't fix the problem.

> Is there a simpler way to reset the state of the device?

It looks like you will have to make a hardware modification - cut the connection between /INT and /RESET on the board - if you can identify which track that might be - or use a soldering iron to heat and lift the /INT pin of the RTC chip, which might be easier, depending on what the chip is (they are amazingly short on information).

> What did I even do wrong ?

Probably nothing serious - it's the design that is at fault. Anything that has the potential to completely cripple a system like that without even trying is just idiotic.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the well written answer. As you can see I have received an answer from the official team which should work.

Comment: Great stuff. I guess they must have answered that same question a million times.