# CONTROLLINO MEGA – Timeout communicating with programmer

Tags: arduino-mega

I’ve been using my CONTROLLINO MEGA since long time ago, but today I uploaded a sketch and now the board is not working. Everytime I try to uploud a sketch, ARDUINO IDE remains in “uploading..” mode and after a while this message appears:

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude done. Thank you.

I have selected the correct board on the correct COM port (I’ve been using the board for months with no problem).

The sketch that I uploaded before this problem is:

```
SoftwareSerial serie(CONTROLLINO_D12, CONTROLLINO_D13);
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
serie.begin(9600);
void loop() {
serie.listen();
while (serie.available() > 0) {
char inByte = serie.read();
Serial.write(inByte);
}
Serial.println();
}
```

Any Idea?? I've checked this topic alredy [Did I Brick my Controllino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22591/did-i-brick-my-controllino),
but dont know how to apply the solution on my CONTROLLINO MEGA

Thank you!!

Comment: Is the "RST" led in front of your controllino on?